# CSS vertical alignment - once again

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I know this question is coming up again and again. Vertical alignment in CSS seems to be a major issue...

I am trying to align the two texts (`Kinesiologie Stammheim` and `Dies ist der Platzhalter für ein Zitat zum Thema Erde`) in the head of this site to the middle: http://www.kine-stammheim.ch/ikmethode.html

My CSS file is here: http://www.kine-stammheim.ch/css/screen/screen-PAGE-layout.css

I tried all the different suggestions which google brings up, `vertical-align:middle;`, `display:inline-block;`, etc. but without success.

What is the correct way to vertical align these text to the middle?

Comment: give line-height: 120px; because the height of the parent element is 120px. this will work if you have a single line of text.

Comment: Just use `line-height:120px` as this is the height of your banner div.

Comment: loose the `line-height` or negative `margin` approach.. it's too specific. there is a better way to vertically center elements.. I'll post it shortly in the answers.

Comment: I will probably have more than one line... And also if this one line is displayed in a small browser window and wraped there is an issue.

Comment: you can read this: [Link](http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/)

Comment: the only way to make `vertical-align:middle;` work properly is to use it with `display:table-cell`

Comment: @Pete woww you're so wrong..

Comment: @avrahamcool please enlighten me, what else can you use it on?

Comment: @Pete the vertical-align property can be used to affect a set of inline or inline-block elements within the same block-level parent.  That is a different concept than how vertical-align controls the behavior of content in a table-cell.

Comment: @avrahamcool I agree with Pete in that neither yours or Marc's solutions can handle text wrapping, which is mentioned in the comments

Comment: Ah ok, I should add to my previous comment then that if you are applying `vertical-align:middle;` to an element to get it's child elements to vertical align, then it will only work with `display:table-cell;`.  If you are applying it to the child element to make it align to the middle of the parent element, then it will do that with inline, or inline-block elements.  As I understand it, doing it on inline elements won't give your the true middle either: Aligns the middle of the element with the middle of lowercase letters in the parent.

Comment: @Pete applying `vertical-align:middle` to inline elements make them align with other inline elements, not to the middle of the parent. now I agree with you. BTW: this is exactly what I do in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Pure CSS, Cross Browser, without specific margin, without absolute positioning and without setting the line-height

Check out this <kbd>[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/2BYzH/)</kbd>

**HTML:** (put everything you want inside `Centered`)

```
<div class="Container">
    <div class="Centered">
        <p>Herzlich Willkommen</p>
        <p>Hier entsteht der Webauftritt der Kinesiologie Stammheim.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.Container
{
    height: 400px; /*For the demo*/
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
    text-align: center; /*optional*/
}
.Container:before
{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.Centered
{
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Explanation:**
I'm adding an empty `inline-block` element (with 100% height) to the container, and making the `Centered` div to align with his middle (which is always the middle of the container)

Comment: yeah.. just saw that someone Downvoted you.. IDK why. you get a +1 from me.

Comment: I can't understand what you did.. css is full of hidden treasure. I love it. :)

Comment: Although this works for the #banner, I don't think it works for #logo? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @danrhul it works with everything.. just use the layout smartly.

Comment: And it can't handle text wrapping onto new lines.

Comment: @danrhul try [This](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/2BYzH/1/) (change the size of the img to whatever you like.. it works perfectly)

Comment: Are you serious?? change the image height only.. not also the `div`s.. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/2BYzH/3/) [BTW: You dont know how to use placehold.it?]

Answer (score 2):

In light of your comments about multi-line text, if you add:

```
#parentElement { display: table; width: 100%; }
#childElement { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;  text-align: center; }
```

This will achieve what you are trying to do, with single, or multi line text. You need to replace `#parentElement` with your two parent elements: `#banner, #logo` and replace `#childElement` with your two child elements: `#banner .quote, #logo .logo_text`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M8hw6/)

Comment: If the quote text is to wrap, then the table-cell approach is a good option.

Answer (score 1):

You have to minor layout problems.

Here is how to fix the first one.

```
<div id="logo">

    <img class="logo_img" src="../../images/logo.png"></img>
    <div class="logo_text"> … </div>

</div>

.logo_img {
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px 20px 10px 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.logo_text {
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 133.33%;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

In the part related to `#logo`, do not float the `img`, keep it as an inline or inline-block element and set `vertical-align: middle`.

For `.logo-text`, add `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle`.

This will position the image and text block in the vertical middle of the header block.

For problem two related to `.quote`,

```
<div id="banner">
    <div class="quote"> … </div>
</div>

.quote {
    font-family: "Times New Roman",Times,serif;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 200%;
    line-height: 120px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

In this case set the `line-height: 120px` to match the height of the image which controls the height of the header block.

**However**, if the quote were to wrap onto a second line, this would not work well and a table-cell approach be better.

Here is the result using Firefox's code inspector:

[image]

Comment: That is absolutely right, if the `.quote` line were to wrap, then there would be large interline spacing, a bit ugly.  For a responsive design and a small screen, I would just use a table-cell (via media queries).

Comment: The solution for the logo works fine. However on small screens the logo_text drops below the logo. That's ok but it is hidden behind the menu. How can I make sure the div with the logo and the logo_text gets enlarged, so everything remains above the menu?

Comment: For a small screen (responsive design via media queries), I might set a min-width to `#logo` to retain enough horizontal space for the logo and the 2-line text block.  You could also let the header take on a vertical format with `#logo` as the first line/section followed by the image/quote panel below it, again for a small screen.  You have many options.

Comment: Hm, but then the `#logo` div moves behind the banner... How can I make sure divs do not overlap or cover each other?

Answer (score 0):

Better declare you parent division as `position:relative` and child division as `position:absolute`, then you can easily adjust this.

Use Left, right, top, bottom to adjust anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code may help you, just edit these classes:

```
.quote {
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
color: white;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
font-style: italic;
font-size: 200%;
line-height: 1.5em;
vertical-align: middle;
display: table-cell;   /*added*/
}

#banner {
background-image: url(../../images/erde.jpg);
background-size: 100% 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
height: 120px;
display: table;    /*added*/
width: 100%;       /*added*/
}
```